# How to solve "Unresolved import: HTML" in Python Development?

Tags: python, html, eclipse, import, anaconda

I'm starting to learn about python development in a new project.
I got setup almost everything right, but only this `import HTML` that keeps given me some error that I don't know how to solve it.

```
import web
import json
from WebServer.forms import mainPageForm, addBugForm, addProblemForm, addProblemTypeForm, versionsDropdownForm,\
                  severitiesDropdownForm, problemTypesDropdownForm, problemsDropdownForm
import BugRecorderCore.controller as ctrl
import BugRecorderCore.validators as vdt
import datetime
import os
from BugRecorderCore.utils import concatenateString
import HTML
//...
```

[image: imports]

I already tried to install [HTML.py](http://www.decalage.info/python/html#attachments) already, but still no success so far.
[image: html.py]

Any idea or advice about this issue ?

**UPDATE**
Following the suggestions from the answers below I got this message:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using anaconda, have you tried installing it the anaconda way?

```
conda install HTML
```

Also do you by any chance have 2 version of Python on your system?

If the package is unavailable you'll have to user `pip`.  If you don't have pip, from your command line write:

```
python get-pip.py
pip install HTML
```

Comment: I tried this command too but it can't download the HTML module for some reason. No, just Anaconda.

Comment: Their docs say if the package is unavailable use `pip`.  If you don't have pip, run the command: `python get-pip.py` then run `pip install HTML`.  [Here is where I found this info](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/faq.html#install-packages)

Answer (score 0):

Looking the given screenshots and tags I suppose your are using `Anaconda` (which I have no experience but it is still Python, anyway) and the IDE is not resolving the import.

1. Make sure you have installed/updated HTML.py

   ```
   conda install HTML
   ```
2. At your IDE go to *Window > Preferences > Python Interpreter*
3. At *Libraries* tab make sure you have the following folders added to your `PYTHONPATH`:

   - C:\Anaconda\Lib
   - C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages
   - C:\Anaconda\Scripts

That should do the trick.

**Important**: try to always install your libraries through `conda` (or `pip` when using Python directly). It will install things where it should be. ;)

Comment: You're right, I'm using Anaconda.
I update my question with a new image about your recommendation. I tried to install HTML with conda but no success.

Comment: I think you should reference `HTML.py` instead of `HTML`. Try `conda install HTML.py` (or change to `update` if you are sure you already have it).