# How to solve Html module not found error in Python?

Tags: python

I am running python 3.7 version and using Pycharm edu. I tried to import the 'html' module. But I am getting the following error,

```
ImportError: No module named html
```

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: You may find useful this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24959259/how-to-solve-unresolved-import-html-in-python-development)[link]

Comment: @HectorIX Thanks Man! That solved it

Comment: Also guys please check the version of python you are using. The html module library is installed in python versions above 2.7.9

Answer (score 0):

> Any idea why this happens?

python throws this error when it can't find tye requested module, make sure that the module correctly installed and you have installed it for python 3.7.